# Angular 8 and assigning variables

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-components, angular-input

In `product.html` I have the following code:

```
<h3>{{product.title}}</h3>
<h4>{{product.categories[0]}}</h4>
<p>{{product.description}}</p>
```

I get the `product` via input (with empty initial values), so `product.ts` looks like this:

```
 @Input() product: Product = {title: '', categories: [''], description: ''};
```

I'd like that `product.html` would look like this:

```
<h3>{{title}}</h3>
<h4>{{subtitle}}</h4>
<p>{{description}}</p>
```

My question is, how can I achieve this?

I've tried for the variables `title, subtitle, description` to simply point to the `product`'s properties (`title, categories[0], description`), so that `product.ts` would look like this:

```
 @Input() product: Product = {title: '', categories: [''], description: ''};
 title = product.title;
 subtitle = product.categories[0];
 description = product.description;
```

But it isn't working right.

Comment: Define accessors? E.g. `get title(): string { return this.product.title; }`

Comment: Set all the instance values inside `ngOnInit` hook.

Comment: @SiddharthPal then they won't get reset if and when the input changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your properties and then set them in the [ngOnChanges](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#onchanges) lifecycle hook.

```
... definition
title: string;
subtitle: string;
description: string;
... inside ngOnChanges
this.title = this.product.title;
this.subtitle = this.product.categories[0];
this.description = this.product.description;
```

The other option is to use functions to get the values:

```
title = () => this.product.title;
subtitle = () => thisproduct.categories[0];
description = () => this.product.description;
```

And use them in your view as:

```
{{title()}}
{{subtitle()}}
{{description()}}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I've tried ngOnInit, but haven't thought about ngOnChanges, it's nice to( finally) see where and how it can be used.

Answer (score 1):

A solution with getters :

```
get title(): string {
  return this.product.title;
}

get subtitle(): string {
  return this.product.categories[0];
}

get description(): string{
  return this.product.description;
}
```

Into the template :

```
<h3>{{title}}</h3>
<h4>{{subtitle}}</h4>
<p>{{description}}</p>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I've never seen getters and setters used in Angular (being a newbie), is this common practice? I'd give your answer a checkmark too, if it was possible to give two.

Comment: It's not specific to Angular but to Typescript (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html) and yes it's a common practice.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
 title: string;
 subtitle: string;
 description: string;

ngOnInit() {
  this.title product.title;
  this.subtitle = product.categories[0];
  this.description = product.description;
}
```